# Merge rows if value from table is the same in PHP

Tags: php, html, pdo

I wanted to ask something.
Im using PHP and PDO to retrieve data from a table.

Right now i use this php code:

```
<div class="containter">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 mt-4">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h3>Drop Τεράτων</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Mob</th>
                            <th>Item</th>
                            <th>Count</th>
                            <th>Drop Chance</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php
                        $query = "SELECT * FROM drop_default";
                        $statement = $conn->prepare($query);
                        $statement->execute();

                        $statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); //PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
                        $result = $statement->fetchAll();
                        if($result) {
                            foreach($result as $row) {
                                ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><?= $row->mob_vnum; ?></td>
                                    <td><?= $row->item_vnum; ?></td>
                                    <td><?= $row->count; ?></td>
                                    <td><?= $row->prob; ?></td>
                                </tr>
                                <?php
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td>No Record Found</td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php
                        }
                    ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My website now shows these data:

```
Mob Item    Count   Drop Chance
8036    12794   1   1000
8036    12794   1   1000
8036    12793   1   1000
```

I want to change the php code, so if mob data is the same, to merge every data into one. For example:

```
Mob Item    Count   Drop Chance
8036    12794   1   1000
        12794   1   1000
        12793   1   1000
```

More specific view:
[image]

Comment: just simply save `mob_vnum` in a temporary container, then it's a matter of checking with an `if` statement while it's iterating, if not the same, print else don't

Comment: you can declare a variable in your foreach which will hold value of $row->mob_vnum; and you can compare both of them and them update it at the end of loop.

Comment: @Kevin im a beginned at coding , so could you help me and give me the example of the code ? if you have time of course... thanks in advance.

Comment: just simply initialize an empty string variable outside the loop, inside the loop check if the previous `mob_vnum` is not equal to current iteration, echo it and set it to the previous, else (if it's the same), echo an empty string: `$prev = ''; foreach { if (prev !== current) set and echo ELSE echo empty string }` along those lines

Comment: @Kevin thanks for your answer. You mean to add $prev = ''; after $result = $statement->fetchAll(); ?? Sorry about my questions but as i said im a beginner...